# NSProgressIndicator's setControlTint has no effect

Tags: colors, nsprogressindicator

I have a very simple task: change the NSProgressIndicator's color into graphite when the progress is paused by user, that is a determinate progress bar. I found the method [setControlTint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProgressIndicator/setControlTint%3a) but after using it there is just no effect. I also searched a lot there is not much clear answers. Is subclass NSProgressIndicator and do some custom drawing a must? I just wonder why this method there and no further document or discussion about proper usage.

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score -2):

See doc:

Doc for NSProgressIndicator
**setControlTint:**

Sets the receiver’s control tint.

```
- (void)setControlTint:(NSControlTint)controlTint
```

Parameters `controlTint` a constant indicating the desired control tint. Valid values for controlTint are described in **NSCell**.

Go to NSCell doc:

**setControlTint**:

Sets the receiver’s control tint.

```
- (void)setControlTint:(NSControlTint)controlTint
```

Parameters controlTint - an **Designated Initializers** value that specifies the tint of the receiver.

**Designated Initializers**

When subclassing `NSCell` you must implement all of the designated initializers. Those methods are: `init`, `initWithCoder:`, `initTextCell:`, and `initImageCell:`.

In to words you must subclassing NSProgressIndicator and **implement all of the designated initializers.** (see above).

Comment: Hi, I'm encountering the same problem and I can't figure out your solution. Could you develop it a bit ? I tried `[toolbarViewProgressIndicator setControlTint:NSGraphiteControlTint]` and it is just not working.

Comment: @Heisennberg,I expanded my answer.

Comment: It's still not working for me either, and I don't understand your answer. NSProgressIndicator does not inherit from NSCell, does it?

Comment: Yes NSProgressIndicator does not inherit from NSCell. In NSCell class we need to look only "Valid values for controlTint"